# How to count the number of account numbers per loan ID entry instead of the total number of entries for that account number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my query to count the number of account number entries if the lt.type is 46, per each loan ID entry. It is currently counting the total number of entries overall.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER)
        OVER(partition by a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) as [Number of 
Tracking Records] 
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND n.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
AND a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()),   
112)
AND l.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
AND n.type = 0
AND a.ACCOUNTNUMBER NOT IN (SELECT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER 
                                    FROM dbo.ACCOUNT a
                INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
                ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
                WHERE lt.type = 36)
) MyQuery
WHERE MyQuery.[Number of Tracking Records] >= 3
ORDER BY [Account Number], MyQuery.[Loan ID]
```

Right now my code is counting the total amount of entries for the account number each time there is an entry for that account and the lt.type of 46.
I want it to count the number of entries for each account number if there is a type 46, but only for each loan ID.
I am attaching some examples of what it is doing now, and what I'd like it to do, along with some sample data.

[This is what my query is doing now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb6tx.png)

[This is what I want my query to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvsYA.png)

[Here is some sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb8wR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to partition by two fields, of which the loan Id is one of them:

```
COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) OVER(partition by a.ACCOUNTNUMBER, l.id)
```